# How to embed a Newest browser control Visual Basic 6?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, vb6

I want to know how to embed IE browser in Visual Basic 6. I already tried `ieframe.dll` active-x internet control but which is not supporting newest browser,  i guess, i only support IE 8 something like that.

Also, i tried to replacing internet control component DLL files, but it failed to register.
so, Any possible method to embedding newest Internet Explorer Browser in Visual Basic 6 ?

thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WebBrowser` control is emulating IE7 unless instructed in registry to emulate higher version. If you need a newer version emulation the registration in registry is per process. You have to add a `DWord` value under

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

with name `MyApp.exe` and value `IEMajor * 1000` i.e. 8000, 9000, etc. Obviously no reason to write anything for versions below IE8

[Here is a complete list of all the values allowed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx) under your process name. You can use `App.EXEName` ot `GetModuleFileName` API to get current process name and auto-wire the value on startup -- `Sub  Main` or `Form_Initialize` -- before loading the `WebBrowser` control.

Comment: this is great and works nice. i'm really appreciate for your effort.

Comment: See https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/may/21/web-browser-control-specifying-the-ie-version for this in much detail.